# Need to use Countif with Indirect to reference a different sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a formula like this =COUNTIF('Program Schedule Loader TCs'!N2:N9994,"PASS")
Now i want to have a formula that always references to column 'N' on the mentioned sheet even after inserting new columns.

Answer (score 1):

You were nearly there - you just need to wrap the range with `INDIRECT()` (remember to add quotes to the range as well).

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Program Schedule Loader TCs'!N2:N9994"),"PASS")
```

This will ALWAYS reference column N, even if by inserting new columns there is no data in column N.

Comment: this, definitely +1